# How can change bar view in bar chart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I need change bars view in barchart in MPAndroidChart like this... [that's how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxGG3.png) Is it possible to set custom bar drawable, or just smooth the corners, or something like this?

[Now I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9AXP.png)

My code:

```
fun barChart(
    activity: Activity,
    chart: BarChart,
    entries: ArrayList<BarEntry>,
    columnsNames: ArrayList<String>,
    colors: ArrayList<Int>,
) {

    val colorsTemplate = intArrayOf(
        Color.rgb(74, 160, 150), Color.rgb(74, 160, 150), Color.rgb(74, 160, 150),
        Color.rgb(74, 160, 150), Color.rgb(74, 160, 150)
    )
    val colors: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    for (color in colorsTemplate) {
        colors.add(color)
    }
    val dataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "")

    val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("0.##")
    dataSet.setValueFormatter(object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            return decimalFormat.format(value)
        }
    })

    dataSet.colors = colors
    val data = BarData(dataSet)
    data.barWidth = 0.5f
    data.setDrawValues(true)
    chart.setData(data)
    chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true)

    val xAxis = chart.getXAxis()
    xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(columnsNames)
    xAxis.position = (XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    xAxis.granularity = 1f
    xAxis.labelCount = columnsNames!!.size
    xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 360f

    chart.legend.isEnabled = false
    chart.description.isEnabled = false
    chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false

    chart.axisLeft.labelCount = 3
    chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f

    chart.animateY(1000)
    chart.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: For rounded bars, try this: https://gist.github.com/xanscale/e971cc4f2f0712a8a3bcc35e85325c27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time after the found solution I am writing an answer to my own question, maybe it will be useful to someone. Thanks [gioravered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649154/gioravered) for the tip

This is code for your chart:

```
val barChartRender =
            RoundedBarChartRender(chart, chart.animator, chart.viewPortHandler)
        barChartRender.initBuffers()
        barChartRender.setRadius(20)
        chart.renderer = barChartRender
```

And this is the code of a new sub class, which render the rounding:

```
class RoundedBarChartRender(
    chart: BarDataProvider?,
    animator: ChartAnimator?,
    viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?
) : BarChartRenderer(chart, animator, viewPortHandler) {
    private val mBarShadowRectBuffer = RectF()
    private var mRadius = 0
    fun setRadius(mRadius: Int) {
        this.mRadius = mRadius
    }

    override fun drawDataSet(c: Canvas, dataSet: IBarDataSet, index: Int) {
        val trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.axisDependency)
        mBarBorderPaint.color = dataSet.barBorderColor
        mBarBorderPaint.strokeWidth = Utils.convertDpToPixel(dataSet.barBorderWidth)
        mShadowPaint.color = dataSet.barShadowColor
        val drawBorder = dataSet.barBorderWidth > 0f
        val phaseX = mAnimator.phaseX
        val phaseY = mAnimator.phaseY
        if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled) {
            mShadowPaint.color = dataSet.barShadowColor
            val barData = mChart.barData
            val barWidth = barData.barWidth
            val barWidthHalf = barWidth / 2.0f
            var x: Float
            var i = 0
            val count = Math.min(
                Math.ceil(
                    (dataSet.entryCount.toFloat() * phaseX).toDouble().toInt().toDouble()
                ), dataSet.entryCount.toDouble()
            )
            while (i < count) {
                val e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(i)
                x = e.x
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.left = x - barWidthHalf
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.right = x + barWidthHalf
                trans.rectValueToPixel(mBarShadowRectBuffer)
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(mBarShadowRectBuffer.right)) {
                    i++
                    continue
                }
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(mBarShadowRectBuffer.left)) break
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.top = mViewPortHandler.contentTop()
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.bottom = mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()
                c.drawRoundRect(mBarRect, mRadius.toFloat(), mRadius.toFloat(), mShadowPaint)
                i++
            }
        }

        // initialize the buffer
        val buffer = mBarBuffers[index]
        buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY)
        buffer.setDataSet(index)
        buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.axisDependency))
        buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.barData.barWidth)
        buffer.feed(dataSet)
        trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer)
        val isSingleColor = dataSet.colors.size == 1
        if (isSingleColor) {
            mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.color
        }
        var j = 0
        while (j < buffer.size()) {
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                j += 4
                continue
            }
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j])) break
            if (!isSingleColor) {
                // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
                // is out of bounds, reuse colors.
                mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.getColor(j / 4)
            }
            if (dataSet.gradientColor != null) {
                val gradientColor = dataSet.gradientColor
                mRenderPaint.shader = LinearGradient(
                    buffer.buffer[j],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                    buffer.buffer[j],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                    gradientColor.startColor,
                    gradientColor.endColor,
                    Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
                )
            }
            if (dataSet.gradientColors != null) {
                mRenderPaint.shader = LinearGradient(
                    buffer.buffer[j],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                    buffer.buffer[j],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                    dataSet.getGradientColor(j / 4).startColor,
                    dataSet.getGradientColor(j / 4).endColor,
                    Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
                )
            }
            val path2 = roundRect(
                RectF(
                    buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3]
                ), mRadius.toFloat(), mRadius.toFloat(), true, true, false, false
            )
            c.drawPath(path2, mRenderPaint)
            if (drawBorder) {
                val path = roundRect(
                    RectF(
                        buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3]
                    ), mRadius.toFloat(), mRadius.toFloat(), true, true, false, false
                )
                c.drawPath(path, mBarBorderPaint)
            }
            j += 4
        }
    }

    private fun roundRect(
        rect: RectF,
        rx: Float,
        ry: Float,
        tl: Boolean,
        tr: Boolean,
        br: Boolean,
        bl: Boolean
    ): Path {
        var rx = rx
        var ry = ry
        val top = rect.top
        val left = rect.left
        val right = rect.right
        val bottom = rect.bottom
        val path = Path()
        if (rx < 0) rx = 0f
        if (ry < 0) ry = 0f
        val width = right - left
        val height = bottom - top
        if (rx > width / 2) rx = width / 2
        if (ry > height / 2) ry = height / 2
        val widthMinusCorners = width - 2 * rx
        val heightMinusCorners = height - 2 * ry
        path.moveTo(right, top + ry)
        if (tr) path.rQuadTo(0f, -ry, -rx, -ry) //top-right corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(0f, -ry)
            path.rLineTo(-rx, 0f)
        }
        path.rLineTo(-widthMinusCorners, 0f)
        if (tl) path.rQuadTo(-rx, 0f, -rx, ry) //top-left corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(-rx, 0f)
            path.rLineTo(0f, ry)
        }
        path.rLineTo(0f, heightMinusCorners)
        if (bl) path.rQuadTo(0f, ry, rx, ry) //bottom-left corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(0f, ry)
            path.rLineTo(rx, 0f)
        }
        path.rLineTo(widthMinusCorners, 0f)
        if (br) path.rQuadTo(rx, 0f, rx, -ry) //bottom-right corner
        else {
            path.rLineTo(rx, 0f)
            path.rLineTo(0f, -ry)
        }
        path.rLineTo(0f, -heightMinusCorners)
        path.close() //Given close, last lineto can be removed.
        return path
    }
}
```